# Label along the line plot in GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I wished to write the label of each line along its respective line plot. Is it possible for Gnuplot to mention the label near the end of the line plot by itself without resorting to manually mention the label locations in the plot?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In recent gnuplot version you can use the `title at end` feature:

```
plot "patb.txt" title "patb rand" at end
```

you might want to change the right margin a bit via `set rmargin 20`

I would suggest to doit manually since he only options for `at` are `begin` or `end` (from `help plot title`)